# How to get the contents of a pandas DateFrame single row without its index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataFrame which consists of many columns but just one row. When I iterate through each column to get the contain of each row, I get 2 separate numbers; namely one for the index and the number itself. 
 Assuming that df is my dataFrame, I do the following

```
for k,v in df.iteritems():

      if df[k]>df.mean(axis=1):
         print(" do something")
```

I get the following error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

When I print df[k], I have two values 0  num

How can I drop the first value?

**Edit:**

This is the structure of my dataframe

```
     column1    column2    column3
  0     2           3          -4
```

I now have

```
for k,v in df.iteritems():

      if df[k][0]>3* abs(df.mean(axis=1)):
         print(" do something")
```

and the error is now :`TypeError: len() of unsized object`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You get a `Series` returned, to get just the scalar value then just do:

```
df[k].values[0]
```

Example:

```
In [190]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abc'), data = np.random.randn(1,3))
df

Out[190]:
          a         b         c
0  0.994306 -0.340043 -0.551422

In [191]:    
for col in df:
    print(df[col].values[0])

0.994306161647
-0.340042912281
-0.551421752498
```

Also this would work too if you hate typing:

```
df[k][0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But why do I now get a problem with the length:                          TypeError: len() of unsized object?

Comment: Please post raw input data and code for your error, as my code works